# Best Python Module for HTML parsing

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

I have a website updater(people can update content(text) not the look of the website) which has HTML, javascript as the front end languages & python as the back-end/server side.

I am finding that updating HTML is very difficult from the front end because when I grab the updated HTML by **ele.innerHTML** or **$(ele).html()** gives altered HTML depending on the browser(DAMN IE).

**So I have decided to update my HTML from the backend, ie, in Python**

What do you think is the best python module to parse HTML & grab information?

My requirements are:
- that the module be atleast in Python 2.5 or less(because of my webhost)
- I will be parsing HTML & finding all the HTML elements that are of the class "updatable"
- For each element of the class "updatable": extract the innerText(not html only text/content)

**Which python module would you suggest is best for this?**
- HTMLParser.py
- htmllib.py
- know of any other python 2.5 compatible modules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been using lxml ( http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html ).  It relatively fast for normal sized html documents and has support for using BeautifulSoup.  As I understand it, BeautifulSoup is no longer supported so for all new projects I've used lxml.

Comment: Beautiful Soup now seems to be active again, with a release from July 3 2012. http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Answer (score 8):

For parsing HTML I would suggest you take a look at Beautiful Soup. It's pretty powerful and can deal with some messed up markup as well.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Check this out and see if it helps you out! Hope it does.

Comment: As a heads up, BeautifulSoup is no longer actively support by it's author and the core dependency SQMLParser was deprecated for Python3.  http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/3.1-problems.html

Comment: My bad, wasn't aware of that, I'll up the lxml option in that case.

Comment: It's really unfortunate as BeautifulSoup is still a great tool.